# How can i generate html report in jmeter with response body

Tags: jmeter

I have made these settings in my jmeter.properties file to save my response data when there is a failure

`jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml`

```
#jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=false

jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=true
```

So with these settings i was able to save the responses and view them using jtl file after i run the script from non gui
But the problem is with this setting jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml i am unable to generate html report
I wanted to generate html report with response body..can someone please help me out

Answer (score 1):

As of [JMeter 5.3](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-3-released-td5728863.html) you cannot generate HTML reporting dashboard from .jtl files in XML format, [according to the documentation:](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#overview)

> The dashboard generator is a modular extension of JMeter. Its default behavior is to read and process samples **from CSV files** to generate HTML files containing graph views. It can generate the report at end of a load test or on demand.

The easiest way of getting the response data into the HTML reporting dashboard is artificially failing the sampler(s) via [JSR223 Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial) and setting assertion failure message to be current sampler's response data, example code:

```
AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
AssertionResult.setFailureMessage(prev.getResponseDataAsString())
```

You will be able to get something like:

[image]

If this solution is not acceptable you can amend the [report-template](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/tree/rel/v5.3/bin/report-template) to represent whatever you want (the knowledge of Java and [Freemarker](https://freemarker.apache.org/) will be required)

Comment: Can u pls let me know how can we do the same using bean shell scripting?Also for every sampler we cannot add this script.So do we have any alternative solution which is applicable for all samplers